# Excel - filtering results limited to first 10,000 lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am working on spreadsheet but every time I tried to  filter the filtering stops at 10,000 lines
(not all items showing )

Is there any alternative solution like formula or another option?

Comment: At the moment you activate the auto-filters, Excel reads the consecutive lines top down. If you add lines later, they will not be added automatically. Try deactivating the Auto-Filters; then select all your data, and switch them back on.

Answer (score -1):

Ans :- As usual do the vlook-up. Filter out and check first 10000 lines and analyse the data. Then remove filter and delete 1st 10000 lines. Then again filter out and check next 10000 lines, analyse your data....And so on....
Hope this resolved your issue...
And requesting MS to fix it with your team...